# building a tree from a csv file using python

Tags: python, csv, tree

My csv file has the following format

```
Col1        Col2
a           b
b           c
c           d
d           e
x           b
y           c
z           c
m           x
h           b
i           b
```

I will create a dictionary to hold this data like this

```
{ b:[a,x,h,i] , c:[b,y,z], d:[c], e:[d], x:[m] }
```

From this dictionary I want to be able to build a hierarchy. For example: when I walk through the dictionary for 'a' I should be able to display

```
 a -> b -> c -> d -> e
```

Similarly for 'y'

```
 y -> c -> d -> e
```

I can think of this as a tree structure and imagine this to be a depth first traversal, but I am unsure about how to achieve this with a dictionary in python. This would not be a decision tree or a binary tree etc.

Comment: what operations do you need on the data? you need the sequence of jumps from one col to the other? how many rows is the sequence?

Comment: Why do you want to build the dictionary this way, if the look-ups you want to do are in the reverse direction?  Why not simply build the dicitonary the way you want to look things up, i.e. using the first column as keys and the second column as values?

Comment: I'm surprised there isn't an off-the-shelf solution for this in Python, especially when you consider just about everything under the sun has been captured as a convenient 3rd party library in the language.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**Python-Graph**](http://code.google.com/p/python-graph/).

```
pairs = read_from_csv(...)

from pygraph.classes.digraph import digraph 
gr = digraph()
gr.add_nodes(set([x for (x,y) in pairs]+[y for (x,y) in pairs]))

for pair in pairs:
    gr.add_edge(pair)

#and now you can do something with the graph...

from pygraph.algorithms.searching import depth_first_search

print ' -> '.join(depth_first_search(gr, root='a')[1])
print ' -> '.join(depth_first_search(gr, root='y')[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

```
filedict = {}
for row in file:
  try:
    filedict[row.col2].append(row.col1)
  except:
    filedict[row.col2] = [row.col1]
invdict = dict((v,k) for k, v in filedict.iteritems())
def parse(start):
  if start not in invdict:
    return []
  next = invdict[start]
  return [next] + parse(next)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that just uses dictionaries:

```
from itertools import chain

def walk(d, k):
    print k,
    while k in d:
        k = d[k]
        print '->', k,

data = {'b': ['a','x','h','i'], 'c': ['b','y','z'], 'd': ['c'], 'e': ['d'], 'x': ['m']}
hierarchy = dict(chain(*([(c, p) for c in l] for p, l in data.iteritems())))
# {'a':'b', 'c':'d', 'b':'c', 'd':'e', 'i':'b', 'h':'b', 'm':'x', 'y':'c', 'x':'b', 'z':'c'}

walk(hierarchy, 'a') # prints 'a -> b -> c -> d -> e'
walk(hierarchy, 'y') # prints 'y -> c -> d -> e'
```